# How to change text on a button in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a button but I want it change the text every time I press it (e.g. on and off).

This is my button class.

```
class TextSend extends StatelessWidget {
String title;
Function onTap;
TextSend(this.title, this.onTap);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return RaisedButton(
    color: Colors.green,
    disabledColor: Colors.grey,
    textColor: Colors.white,
    disabledTextColor: Colors.black38,
    child: title,
    onPressed: onTap,
  );
}
}
```

This is the button instance, where I call it on another class:

```
TextSend('Button on', Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MQTTView()));),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In order to change the text , you need to change the Stateless widget to Stateful Widget, because Stateless widget is only for static pages that doesn't change content.
2. after that in order to have a text into the button you need to give a Text widget as a child of the RaisedButton ,and not a String .
3. in order to change the text you have to call a function when the button is pressed, that function is gonna change the title variable and after that call "setState" function which is responsible of refreshing the page so that your changes can be displayed

here is your  code modified and should do the job you want. if you miss something just make me know . thanks

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TextSend extends StatefulWidget {
String title;
Function onTTap;
TextSend(this.title, this.onTTap);

  @override
  _TextSendState createState() => _TextSendState();
}

class _TextSendState extends State<TextSend> {


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return RaisedButton(
    color: Colors.green,
    disabledColor: Colors.grey,
    textColor: Colors.white,
    disabledTextColor: Colors.black38,
    child: Text(widget.title),
    onPressed: changeText, //
  );
}


// method responsible of changing the text

changeText(){
  setState(() {
    widget.title='text changed';
  });
}


}
```

Comment: Thank you @Khalil LAABOUDI, it seems to work but how can I use this button on another class?

Comment: How can I call it? (if we have to say better) And it's very kind thank you.

Comment: Thank you, I found my problem!!

Answer (score 0):

You need a [StatefulWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html) class. Flutter documentation has a really nice [tutorial](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/interactive) that shows an example similar to your problem.